# active_model_serializers doesn't use serializer when render command contains more than just an activerecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have active_model_serializers setup in a rails project, and can can successfully use a serializer to display json in such a fashion:

```
render json: @user
```

However, the gem seems to fail to automatically use the serializer if I am including the model object in a more complex json response as such:

```
render json: { "success": true, "something": "xyz", user: @user }
```

I've found that I can do the following to get around it, although its a pain to have to do:

```
render json: { "success": true, "something": "xyz", user: UserSerializer.new(@user) }
```

Additionally, using it as shown above seems to make it not pick up on the root:false option that I have specified as my default_serializer_options in ApplicationController. This means I have to go as far as to put:

```
render json: { "success": true, "something": "xyz", user: UserSerializer.new(@user, root: false) }
```

Is there a better way around this? It seems like having to be so explicit in every single render is going to take away from some the simplicity/benefit of AMS...

** Note: this is rails 4, ruby 2.0, and active_model_serializers 0.8.0

Answer (score 0):

active_model_serializers allows one serializer to inherit from another. To get the result you're looking for, I would make an `ApplicationSerializer` with  `"success"` and `"something"` as attributes. Other serializers can then inherit from that. Basically, something like:

```
  class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    self.root = false
    attributes :success, :something

    def success
      true
    end

    def something
      "xyz"
    end
  end

  class UserSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :name, :email, :etc
  end
```

Note that in my example here, `"success"` and `"something"` will turn out in the json as attributes within the user, not with the user as a separate key. It's totally possible to do that, but it seems like you'd rather just say `render json: @user`.

Comment: That also becomes cumbersome when I would do it for a half-dozen different models though

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like someone took care of this exact problem, but their branch never got merged into ams: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/300

Comment: Ha that's too bad. That poor PR sat for a year and a half with the 'accepted' tag only to be closed! 

I'm not quite sure what you meant about doing the same thing for a half-dozen models. All the model serializers can also inherit from ```ApplicationSerializer```. It can be in it's own file and everything.

Comment: Ugh, this gets even worse when trying to serialize an array of models within a larger hash, because you can't use "each_serializer:" either. Seems like I need to iterate over the models before the render, and serialize each, and than render the array of serializations....